# Is it safe to backup crashed MySQL table?

Tags: backup, database, mysql

The cache table (MyISAM) marked as crashed.

Is it safe to backup before repair?

(I'm worried if the repair process gone wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always back up before performing a repair. There is extensive documentation on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.5/en/myisam-repair.html) of the MySQL site detailing the backup and repair process.